# MySQL JOIN-ing four tables with two of them only with count

Tags: mysql, join, count, left-join

I want to join 4 tables, these are the tables

```
+-----------------------------------------+
|                  User                   |
+----+----------+----------+-------+------+
| id | username | password | email | name |
+----+----------+----------+-------+------+

+----------------------------------+
|               Post               |
+----+--------+-------------+------+
| id | userID | description | time |
+----+--------+-------------+------+

+------------------------------------+
|               Comment              |
+----+--------+--------+------+------+
| id | userID | postID | text | time |
+----+--------+--------+------+------+

+----------------------+
|         Love         |
+----+--------+--------+
| id | userID | postID |
+----+--------+--------+
```

I want to show all posts from all users with count of comments and "Love" marks on them. This is my query right now, but it returns bad values for countComment and countLove:

```
SELECT User.id AS userID, User.username, User.name, Post.id AS postID, Post.description, Post.time, COUNT(Comment.id) AS countComment, COUNT(Love.id) as countLove
FROM User
    JOIN Post ON User.id = Post.userID
    LEFT JOIN Comment ON Comment.postID = Post.id
    LEFT JOIN Love ON Love.postID = Post.id
GROUP BY Post.id
ORDER BY User.id ASC, Post.time DESC
```

Fields I want to see:

```
+--------+----------+------+--------+-------------+------+--------------+-----------+
| userID | username | name | postID | description | time | countComment | countLove |
+--------+----------+------+--------+-------------+------+--------------+-----------+
```

Thank you all for your help guys, I appreciate it really much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do what I wanted using this query:

```
SELECT
    User.id AS userID, User.username, User.name,
    Post.id AS postID, Post.description, Post.time,
    COALESCE(c.count, 0) AS countComment, COALESCE(l.count, 0) AS countLove
FROM User
    JOIN Post ON User.id = Post.userID
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT Comment.postID, COUNT(*) AS count FROM Comment GROUP BY Comment.postID) c ON c.postID = Post.id
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT Love.postID, COUNT(*) AS count FROM Love GROUP BY Love.postID) l ON l.postID = Post.id
ORDER BY User.id ASC, Post.id DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

The query is grouping by post.id.  It looks like user.id needs to be included too.

```
group by user.id, post.id
```

Comment: Still the same output as my query